# Is there a way to reference a parameter value within the same PSD1 file?

Tags: powershell, dsc

Let's say that I have a PSD1 file, with the following code:

```
@{
    AllNodes = @(
    @{
        NodeName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Tags = @{
            Environment = "dev"
            Datacenter = "east 1"
        }
        Data = @{
            ConfigName = [Tags.Environment]-[Tags.Datacenter.replace(" ","-")]
        }
    })
}
```

See how I am trying to reference the "Tags" section later on in the same file? Is there some way to do that, or do I simply need to do so within a separate PS1 file?

Comment: You can't *reference the "Tags" section later on in the same file*. Besides the fact that the object needs to instantiated first, there is no syntax for that.

Comment: What is `AllNodes`?? It starts as an _array_ `@(..` yet it ends as a _hashtable_ `}`.

Comment: @iRon thanks, that was a typo. I think there will be other ways to achieve what I want, but I guess you are right. There is no way to reference it without first creating the object in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, what you're trying to do is *not* supported** (and, if it were, would pose implementation challenges - see bottom section).

In the interest of security (preventing injection of unwanted code and data), **PowerShell strictly limits what is permitted inside a `*.psd1` file**:

- In a nutshell, a `*.psd1` file contains **a *hashtable literal* (`@{ .. }`) whose values must be *literal* values** - the sole exception being the following [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) (which, conceptually, are *constants*): `$true`, `$false`, and `$null` and, depending on context, `$PSCulture` and `$PSUICulture` (with [`Import-LocalizedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-localizeddata) and in module manifests) and, in module manifests only, `$PSScriptRoot` and `$PSEdition` and `$EnabledExperimentalFeatures` (the latter two only in PowerShell (Core) 7+). [DSC]
- Notably, this ***prevents* use of**:

  - Custom and environment variables.

    - Exception: In the context of [DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?view=dsc-1.1) (your example) environment variables (e.g. `$env:COMPUTERNAME`) *are* allowed.
  - Commands and method calls, including via `$(...)` inside an expandable string (`"..."`)

Note: `*.psd1` files are used in the following **contexts**:

- As *[module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) manifests*, such as created with [`New-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest)
- For storing [DSC (Desired State Configuration)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?view=dsc-1.1) [configuration data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configurations/separatingenvdata?view=dsc-1.1#using-configuration-data-to-define-development-and-production-environments).
- As *general-purpose stores of configuration data*, as read by [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile)

  - Note: As of PowerShell 7.2, this use is hampered by the fact that *programmatic creation* of such files isn't supported yet - fixing that has been green-lighted in [GitHub issue #2875](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2875), and is awaiting implementation by the community.
- [Rarely seen in practice] In [script internationalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Internationalization), via [`Import-LocalizedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-localizeddata) or via intra-script [`DATA` sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Data_Sections).

---

As for **your idea**:

Hypothetically allowing intra-hashtable cross-references:

- is certainly desirable in order to avoid repetition and reduce the maintenance burden.
- is unproblematic from a *security* standpoint, given that no *outside* values would be referenced.
- is challenging from an *implementation* perspective, however:

  - A contextual automatic variable such as `$this` (which already exists in `class`es, for instance) would have to be defined in order to be able to refer to other entries in the same hashtable.

    - In order to reference a specific key, e.g. `$this.AllNodes.Tags.Environment`, inside an expandable string (`"..."`), you would then need to use `$(...)` , which is currently not permitted.
  - Cyclical dependencies between entries would have to be checked for and prevented.

If you feel strongly enough about having such a feature, I encourage you to [submit a feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new/choose).

Comment: thank you for such a well thought out and detailed answer. You are absolutely right on all points except, it seems, $env:COMPUTERNAME. I am using this PSD1 file for DSC purposes, and it does pass that value back as the Node value, such as:

```
Node $AllNodes.NodeName
```

Perhaps it is only permitted in this specific instance, or for this use case?

Comment: @naa2785, thanks for that correction: I had completely missed the DSC angle - please see my update. Yes, I do think that DSC is special-cased with respect to environment variables, but it's hard to tell for sure, absent explicit documentation of the constraints placed on `*.psd1` files in the various contexts they are used in.